# "$(...)[0].append is not a function" with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append a string to a page. If I write `$('.txt')` in the console, it returns:

[image]

If I write `$('.txt')`, it returns the first `.txt`.

If I write `$('.txt').append('<div><span>TEEST</span></div>')` in the console, it appends "TEEST" to all `.txt`s in the page.

But if I write `$('.txt')[0].append('<div><span>TEEST</span></div>')`
it returns:

[image]

Why is this? How I can append to a specific DOM element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[0]` gets the first actual DOM element—not the jQuery object. `append` is a jQuery-specific function, so you can't call it on regular DOM elements (like those that are returned from `getElementById`).

You want [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('.txt').eq(0).append('<div><span>TEEST</span></div>');
```

You could also use the [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
$('.txt:first').append('<div><span>TEEST</span></div>');
```